# Generate unique id for object on both client and server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a simple class which exists on both the client and the server in a package.

```
import {Random} from 'meteor/random'
import {EventEmitter} from 'events'

export class MySpecialClass extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super()
    // ... omitted
    this._id = Random.id()
  }
}
```

However, when I instance this class, it would seem that the generated id is different for both client and server.

Is there a way to generate a unique id on an instance of an object for both client and server?

Comment: What's the underlying goal? What's requiring you to generate your own ids?

Answer (score 0):

You will have a different instance of your class on your server and each client so it makes sense that the random id is different for each. To have the same id you'd need to create it on the server and then have the client obtain that id via [meteor method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods)

Or you could store the ids in a Meteor collection, in which case the data will be synchronized between the server and client.